Minimal s-t cut with two or more disconnections
I have encounter a network disconnecting problem can be abstracted as a generalized version of s-t minimal-cut problem.
The standard s-t min-cut problem is the following. Consider a digraph G=(V, E) with a nonnegative weight for every edge E and a pair of nodes (s, t) where s is the source and t is the terminal. Find a set of edges C with a minimal weight sum such that by removing C from E in the graph G (resulting in a subgraph G'), from s we can no longer reach t. This s-t min-cut problem have been well solved by max-flow-min-cut theorem and can be solved using many algorithms such as push-relabel etc.
Notice that by putting any one edge in the min-cut C back to the subgraph G', t is again reachable from s. The problem I am encountering is: I want to disconnect t from s with a stronger cut so that the disconnection is not recoverable so easily. Hence, what I want to do is to find a cut, denoted as C2, of a minimal weight such that: (1) by removing C2 from E, t is not reachable from s in the subgraph G', and (2) to recover the reachability of t from s, at least k=2 edges in C2 must be put back in G'.
(If k=1, the problem is exactly the standard s-t min-cut problem.)
I have tried to generalize max-flow-min-cut theorem to my case but seems difficult (or impossible). On the other hand, I have a strong feeling that the problem is not NP (at least for a fixed value of k).
My current solution is to apply min-cut three times to obtain a solution: find a min-cut C which splits G into two subgraphs Gs and Gt; for Gs and Gt find min-cuts Cs and Ct; select C+Cs or C+Ct with the smaller weight. But I cannot be sure that such a ``greedy'' solution is globally optimal.
So, does anyone have some clue on efficient algorithms to find a globally optimal solution, or clues for the difficulty of the problem?

You might find the computer science community a better place for answers.

@BrettHale They might, but questions about algorithms are explicitly on-topic here on Stack Overflow as well.
